# Outlook Addin: Avoid open items limit

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

My Outlook addin (VB.net) iterates through mail items and computes their size, like so:

```
For Each m in fol.Items
     b = b + m.Size
Next
```

This works well, unless the Exchange folder has more than about 250 items in it, in which case I get an exception `Your server administrator has limited the number of items you can open simultaneously.` I understand from this that my code doesn't release each mail item as it iterates, so I'm ending up with hundreds of 'open' files in Outlook.

I attempted to add a `m.Close()` line to the loop, but I [see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860308%28v=office.15%29.aspx) that this isn't the desired behavior.

How can I release the objects as I process them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Marshal.ReleaseComObject is a good idea. Secondly, "for each" loop in .Net tends to keep all collection items referenced until the loop exits - use a "for" loop instead.

And most importantly, there is absolutely no reason to open all items in a folder - use the Table object (MAPIFolder.GetTable). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.table(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, especially on using the Table object. I implemented it today and it's about 40 times faster in my environment  :)

Comment: Is there any way to move the item from a Table set result? It looks like i need to map it back to an Outlook.MailItem for that (using GetItemById()), and lose all the benefits of GetTable().

Comment: Why not simply copy the entry ids to your own list or map?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to

```
For Each m in fol.Items
    b = b + m.Size
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(m)
Next
```

It seems inefficient, but it works.